# RegExp to match depending on previous match

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I have a huge (~1000 lines) .htaccess file that I need to clean up from redundant 301 redirects.

I was thinking of using RegExp to help but I reached my limit in this.

All the redirects that I need to remove are on the same pattern

`Redirect 301 /visite/ /fr/visite/`

In that case, I want to match that what follows the "Redirect 301" is the same as what follows with the addition of /LANG (I have /fr /en and /de) and remove the line completely.

Basically, anything that matches the following needs to be removed

`Redirect 301 /some_URL/ /LANG/some_URL/`

However, some redirects need to remain active, such as below.

`Redirect 301 /lavaux-vineyard /en/explore/unesco-listed-lavaux-vineyard-terraces/`

Here is a link to the complete file in question: https://gofile.io/d/l3xC0k

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: Question: how is the language to be used in the target path defined? So which language a path should get redirected to? Since you have two languages this has to be decided somehow when the language is _not_ specified in the path to be redirected, as it currently looks...

Comment: There is now an automatic language redirection in the CMS, which makes the redirect automatic to the right language. ie. on a FR browser, if I type domain.com/url_in_german -> I will end up automatically on domain.com/fr/url_in_french.

Comment: And how does that answer my question? Do you want to express that it is irrelevant, so that the redirection should be statically implemented to _any_ such language code, so for example `/fr/`?

Comment: Yes, if I understand your question correctly, language is irrelevant in the redirects.

Comment: _“some redirects need to remain active, such as below”_ - I don’t find that one in your sample file to begin with? In fact, assuming you want to also remove the following formats, `Redirect 301 /decouvrir/?cat_id=1 /fr/decouvrir/?cat_id=1`, I don’t find _anything_ in there that should _survive_ …?

Comment: The file you linked shows a catalog of rules that does not really match what you sketch in the question. The file shows some different patterns, not a single one. However one can give the general advice: implement a few generic rules for redirections, I suggest you use the rewriting module with its flexible `RewriteRule` directive. You specify more specific rules earlier, so further up in your set of rules. Exceptions which should _not_ get treated belong at the beginning. Something along the line `RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/ /fr${REQUEST_URI} [R=301,END]` should get you started...